# react router page not able to refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I want to try nested routing but it is not working

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pmkwknz0mj)

**Scenario:**
when I route for first time on **/category/bags** it is rendering correctly 
but when I refresh on this page it is giving me error page **Not found**

I tried with **this.props.match.url and  this.props.match.path** but here I am getting error like there is no prop **match.url**

I have tried following links

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

[How to include the Match object into a ReactJs component class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066859/how-to-include-the-match-object-into-a-reactjs-component-class)

[Nested routes with react router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

Comment: have a look to my answer and mark it as accepted if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your code and found that you are using exact in parent routing:

```
<Route exact path="/category" component={Category} />
```

If you remove the exact from parent routing then it will work fine:

```
<Route path="/category" component={Category} />
```

Comment: It worked Thanks..but exact is used to make sure correct routes are rendered not all present in given route e.g. `/category` . can you explain why it was not working? if route **/category/bags** renders on first time then it should render on refresh also

Comment: This is the way react router exact is meant to work, to know more you can refer following blog https://www.sitepoint.com/react-router-v4-complete-guide/

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `ConnectedRouter from ‘react-router-redux’`  instead of `BrowserRouter from 'react-router-dom'`

This article i hope can help you :

https://medium.com/@Dragonza/react-router-problem-with-gh-pages-c93a5e243819